# Complex Grid with Bootstrap 3.3.7 (not updating) and center/middles not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap 3.3.7 and I'm trying to make a grid that has the layout that looks like this:

Issues are centering image/text to center/middle of the column/rows.

- Jon Doe centered in first column
- Jake, Billy, Will being set to the middle of the left combo box.

[image]

However It looks like this:

[image]

I have tried the following with out any luck:

```
.vcenter {
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
float: none;
}

.vertical-align {
    display: block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.align-items-center {
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.d-flex {
    display: -ms-flexbox !important;
    display: flex !important;
}

.col-centered {
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.vcenter {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: none;
}

.positionMe {
    position:center;
}
```

Here is my working layout:

```
<form class="container">
        <div class="row table-bordered col-md-12">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <img src="~/Content/images/PersonSolid.svg" alt="Person Silhouette" style="height: 80px;" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 h4">Jon Doe</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 top" align="center">
                <label class="control-label">Years Worked</label>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <select class="form-control" aria-selected="False">
                            <option value="" hidden></option>
                            <option value="1">1</option>
                            <option value="2">2</option>
                            <option value="3">3</option>
                            <option value="4">4</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <select class="form-control" aria-selected="False">
                            <option value="" hidden></option>
                            <option value="1">1</option>
                            <option value="2">2</option>
                            <option value="3">3</option>
                            <option value="4">4</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <select class="form-control" aria-selected="False">
                            <option value="" hidden></option>
                            <option value="1">1</option>
                            <option value="2">2</option>
                            <option value="3">3</option>
                            <option value="4">4</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <select class="form-control" aria-selected="False">
                            <option value="" hidden></option>
                            <option value="1">1</option>
                            <option value="2">2</option>
                            <option value="3">3</option>
                            <option value="4">4</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4" align="left">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-2">
                        <img src="~/Content/images/PersonSolid.svg" alt="Person Silhouette" style="height: 50px;" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 h5">Jake Johnson</div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-2">
                        <img src="~/Content/images/PersonSolid.svg" alt="Person Silhouette" style="height: 50px;" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 h5">Billy Jack</div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-2">
                        <img src="~/Content/images/PersonSolid.svg" alt="Person Silhouette" style="height: 50px;" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 h5">Will Franklin</div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-2">
                        <img src="~/Content/images/PersonSolid.svg" alt="Person Silhouette" style="height: 50px;" />
                    </div>
                    <div class=" col-md-6 h5">Jack Thomas</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

I can't seem to get this layout to work the way I need it to, what am I doing wrong?

**FEEDBACK**: If this scenario/question could be improved, please let me know.

Comment: Is anyone else looking at this thinking it should work as well?

Comment: It seems like it's been a while with no response.
Is there something I can change to improve getting feedback?